# Delegate between Container Views without using Segue

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicontainerview

I'm trying to pass text from one textField to another textField (both of them are located in two different containerViews). I try to accomplish this with delegate. I've already read tons of related questions here, at stack overflow and read a couple of articles, so, I think I'm doing well except one thing: I don't know how to delegate without segue. Here's the code:

```
    protocol AddOneWordViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func changeTexeValue(_ text: String?)
}

class AddOneWordViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var oneWordAddWord: UITextField!
    weak var delegate: AddOneWordViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func addOneWordWordChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        self.delegate?.changeTexeValue(oneWordAddWord.text!)
        print ("Value of the textField did change \(oneWordAddWord.text!)")
    } // this action is from textField, named "Value Changed"
}
    class AddTwoWordsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, AddOneWordViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var twoWordsAddWord: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

    func changeTexeValue(_ text: String?) {
        self.twoWordsAddWord.text = text
        print("Delegate is working")
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to confirm the delegate to AddTwoWordsViewController otherwise it won't work

Comment: What currently happens when you attempt to add the word but inputting text in the AddOneWordViewController's text field?

Comment: changeTexeValue method in AddTwoWordsViewController will not be called

Comment: Also, you need to set the textfield delegate in AddOneWordViewController to self. And shouldn't you only call the delegate when the user is done entering text (i.e. they are no longer actively inputting text) by using the uitextfield delegate textFieldDidEndEditing? You don't need to set up an IBAction for this. To simplify this you could add a button in your container called "Save" and create an IBAction that grabs the contents of the text field when the user taps the button (self.oneWordAddWord.text).

Comment: I know I should to confirm the delegate to AddTwoWordsViewController, but how? I didn't find solution without using segues.

Comment: As for textFieldDidEndEditing and button Save: they don't suit me much in this case, but is there any difference between them and my approacg? If implementing one of those methods will be easier, I'm agree. Also, I can switch between container views by using segmented controll, so all my container views are located in one view controller (if it can help to find the solution)

Comment: can I please have a look on your two container view how they are called ?

Comment: [This](http://i-fotki.info/22/a56b9d27634f65d8fc3924565bcacd4f05e47d283039546.png.html) is how my storyboard looks like now. For containers I have AddOneWordViewController, AddTwoWordsViewController for first and second respectively and so on (4 total). As for the example, It will be easier to work with 2 containers